# Random Lookup for Excel

Tags: excel, text, random, selection

I want to do a random lookup on a list of data. I used Vlookup but that only returns the first cell that match. Please help to random select from the list.

**Data: $A$1:$B$12**

```
CHESSCY 3562908

CHESSCY 5917972

CHESSCY 9120332

CHESSCY 1034603

CHESSCY 7267341



MANCY   9344508

MANCY   7246578

MANCY   8598782

MANCY   3522520

MANCY   8062641

MANCY   9191026
```

Formula:

```
CHESSCY **3562908** >> =VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)

CHESSCY **3562908** >> =VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)


MANCY   **9344508** >> =VLOOKUP(D4,$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)

MANCY   **9344508** >> =VLOOKUP(D5,$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the items in column A are all grouped together, the formula that I have written here will work.

---

### **GROUPED TOGETHER**

[image]

---

### **NOT GROUPED TOGETHER**

[image: ![enter image description here]

If the items appear like they do in the "NOT GROUPED TOGETHER" image, you will need to sort your data by column A either ascending or descending (Doesn't matter which one).

You can then Enter this formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,INDEX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1),RANDBETWEEN(MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$11,0),MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$11,0)+COUNTIF(A2:$A$11,E2)-1)))
```

[image]